# Getting current value and passing it to another function

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

```
        A          B
1      Date       Data
2    1/1/2014       1
3    1/2/2014       2
4    3/5/2014       3
```

I wanted to sum up rows for certain months. With `month` I can get the month and `sumif` lets me to sum rows that only meet the criteria. However since I don't know how to get the value of the cell and pass it to `month` I have to create a new column just for the month. And now the formula looks like:

```
=sumif(C:C,"=1",B:B)
```

I don't want to specify a column just for the month. Is there a way I can get the value of the cell and pass it to `month` for comparison (without using a new column)?

Comment: I could not compare the outcome of month() function to a date... If you find something, do update here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
=SUMIFS(B:B,A:A,">="&DATE(year,month,1),A:A,"<"&DATE(year,month+1,1))
```

Comment: That's not quite what I'm trying to do. I want to compare the months to a number I define. In pseudo code it's something like this `month(CURRENT_CELL) = 1` but I couldn't transform this into an excel formula.

Comment: Right, so if you want "month = 1", then you'd put in "DATE(2014,1,1)" and "DATE(2014,2,1)".  Unless you mean the month irregardless of year?

Comment: @DarMoon - I just reread your answer and I see what you are doing. It actually does what I'm trying to do (although I'm sure about December). Big thanks but is this the only way to do it?

Comment: The only way that I can think of, short of writing your own function. Do you know VBA?

Comment: I don't know a lot about VBA but I do know a bit. I would definitely like to know a VBA solution. (In my previous comment there's a small typo. It should be `I'm not sure about`)

Comment: It'd be something like this:
`Function SumMonth(xlDateRange As Range, intMonth As Integer, xlValueRange As Range) As Integer
  Dim intSum As Integer
  intSum = 0
  Dim xlCell As Range
  For Each xlCell In xlDateRange
    If Month(xlCell.Value) = intMonth Then
      intSum = intSum + Excel.ActiveSheet.Cells(xlCell.Row, xlValueRange.Column)
    End If
  Next
  SumMonth = intSum
End Function`
Mind you, I haven't added in error checking, and it assumes the rows of the date and value are the same, and that the range is only one column, but hopefully it's a start.

Answer (score 0):

```
   Date Data                
01-06-2014  5           Day      1 
02-06-2014  6           Month    6 
03-06-2014  7           Year     2 014 
04-06-2014  8               
05-06-2014  9               
06-06-2014  4               
07-06-2014  2               
08-06-2014  3               
09-06-2014  1               
10-06-2014  5               
           50               

    =SUMIFS(E9:E18,$D$9:$D$18,">="&DATE(I11,I10,I9),$D$9:$D$18,"<"&DATE(I11,I10+1,I9))
```